# Running Product based on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a "running product" column in Excel. However, the running product is based on another column, a "group". Consider the example below.

[image: Example File Image]

Here, Column A is my group, and each group has multiple items in it (column B). Column C is what I need a running product on, and Column D is the output column. Cell D2 is 0.2 because it is the first item in group 0. Cell D3 is 0.02 since it is the product of item 0 and item 1 in group 0. This continues until we get to group 1, which is when the running product "resets" and starts applying the running product only to group 1, so on and so forth.

I'd like to do this with an formula, and not VBA if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula into D2, then copy\fill it down the D column:

```
=IF(A2=A1,D1*C2,C2)
```

Comment: Note you could use the same technique for your "ITEM" column, like so: `=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,0)`

Comment: Excellent solution! I would have never thought of exploiting relative references like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following **IF function**:

> =IF(B2=0,C2,D1*C2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In D2 try,

```
=PRODUCT(INDEX(C:C, MATCH(A2, A:A, 0)):C2)
```

[image]